# sorting is not working on gridview in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I use a gridview on my asp.net page. And write a code for sorting, but the problem is that the sorting is not working. Can you please tell me what i am doing mistake.

**Code for bind the gridview**

```
DataSet _ds = _fOrderWrapper.ExecuteDataSet();
   ViewState["FOrders"] = _rows;
   lblFinalisedCount.Text = _ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
   GridOpen.DataSource = _ds.Tables[0];
   ViewState["dt"] = _ds.Tables[0];
   ViewState["sort"] = "ASC";
    GridOpen.DataBind();
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
```

Sorting Event code :

```
try
    {
        DataTable dt1 = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
        if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["sort"]) == "ASC")
            {
                dt1.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression +" " + "DESC";
                ViewState["sort"] = "Desc";
            }
            else
            {
                dt1.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression +" "+ "ASC";
                ViewState["sort"] = "ASC";
            }
            GridOpen.DataSource = dt1;
            GridOpen.DataBind();
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code *might* be hitting the sorting event code first, and then executing the regular data binding code second. The second data binding wipes out the effect of the first data binding. Try putting breakpoints in each location. When ASP.NET processes a request for an update panel, it runs the entire page life-cycle, not merely the event handler for the thing that triggered the update.

EDIT after further review:

Your code does this:

```
dt1.DefaultView.Sort = ...
```

Which changes the sorting for the default DataView associated with the DataTable.

But then it sets the data source for the gridview to the DataTable itself.

```
GridOpen.DataSource = dt1;
```

The Default DataView is not being used for data binding, I believe. (Been a while since I've done this, I might still be wrong).

I think you need to bind the GridView to the default DataView:

```
GridOpen.DataSource = dt1.DefaultView;
```

I think the reason the DefaultView is not automatically used when binding to the DataTable is that you would not otherwise have any way to bypass a DataView when binding to the data source.

Comment: thnaks for your reply i did that when i press for sorting in gridview, when i assign the datatable to the gridview i show that there is not shorting performed in that datatable that is assign to my gridview

Comment: means my dt1 is same data without sorted

Comment: the gridview binding function is in `if (!IsPostBack)
        {   BindFinalizedGrid();  }` so this is not binding my gridview again

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's another thing. Don't bind the GridView to the DataTable. DataTables are always sorted in the order they came out of the database, which you aren't changing. Bind the GridView to the DataView -- in your case, the `dt1.DefaultView` DataView

Comment: ya that's right . i did this `GridOpen.DataSource = dt1.DefaultView;` I am giving you mark up please add this part in your answer may be someone again help with this